# Using Webmail with Nodemailer

Tags: node.js, express, cpanel, nodemailer, webmail

I used gmail with node mailer to create a login system in js node.
In development mode I used gmail.

```
const sendEmail = async options =>{
//1)Create a transporter
// const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service: 'gmail',
     auth: {
         user: process.env.EMAIL_SEND_SESSION,
         pass: process.env.EMAIL_SEND_PASSWORD,
   }
});
//2) Define the mail options
const mailOptions = {
    from:'Creative Point <test764@gmail.com>',
    to:options.email,
    subject:options.subject,
    html:options.message
}
//3) Actually send the email
await transporter.sendMail(mailOptions);
};
```

But in production mode I would like to use webmail,I received when I created the data and port account on cpanel.

```
const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport({
    service:'smtp.specialsoft.ro ',
    port: 465,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_SEND_SESSIONCPANEL,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_SEND_PASSWORDCPANEL,
  }
});
```

But it gives me the next mistake.

```
Error: There was an error sending the email.Try again later!Error: Invalid login: 535-5.7.8 Username 
and Password not accepted. Learn more at
 535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials g20sm3266545ejz.88 - gsmtp
at C:\Users\Cosmin\Desktop\Authentification System  Node 
 JS,Express,JsonWebToken\controllers\sessionController.js:56:21
at processTicksAndRejections (internal/process/task_queues.js:93:5)
```

I haven't found anything relevant on the internet about this error.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I solved the problem by following the steps below.

1. I installed a module: **nodemailer-smtp-transport**.

   ```
    const smtpTransport = require('nodemailer-smtp-transport');
   ```
2. I corrected the host name and some options.

   ```
   host:'mail.mydomani.ro'
   secureConnection: false,
   tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    }
   ```

3)I integrated the module **nodemailer-smtp-transport** in the transporter.

```
 const transporter = nodemailer.createTransport(smtpTransport({
    host:'mail.mydomanin.ro',
    secureConnection: false,
    tls: {
      rejectUnauthorized: false
    },
    port: 587,
    auth: {
        user: process.env.EMAIL_SEND_SESSION,
        pass: process.env.EMAIL_SEND_PASSWORD,
  }
}));
```

Comment: I have suffered with nodemailer for long. Thanks very much

Comment: Such a life saver, after 2 days of toil, thank you for this answer!!